# Bootstrap Hide modal and Show other modal event triggering incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a button in the modal that appears onload called `.giveawayApplyNow`. On click the following code executes:

```
$('.giveawayApplyNow').click(function() {
    $('#GiveawayModal').modal('hide');
    $('#GiveawayModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#EligibilityModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

This code closes the current modal and shows a new one. This works fine.

The issue that I am having is that I have a close icon on that same modal `.giveawayClose`. If I use the `.giveawayApplyNow` to open up the new modal, then close that modal, reopen the first modal by clicking the "Learn more" button `.learnMorebtn` and bring up the original modal again, when clicking the `.giveawayClose` button, it is executing my `$('.giveawayApplyNow').click(function()` which closes the current modal and opens the second one, instead of just closing the modal.

Why is this?

**EDIT: Just realized that this not just based on clicking the close button but is triggered whenever close the giveaway modal in any way (for example clicking outside the modal to close it)**

```js
$( window ).on( "load", function() { 
    $('#GiveawayModal').modal();
    
});


$('.learnMorebtn').click(function() {
    $('#GiveawayModal').modal('show');
});

$('.giveawayClose').click(function() {
    $('#GiveawayModal').modal('hide');
});

$('.applyNowbtn, .secondaryheadingBtn').click(function() {
    $('#EligibilityModal').modal('show');
});

$('.eligibilityClose').click(function() {
    $('#EligibilityModal').modal('hide');
});

$('.giveawayApplyNow').click(function() {
    $('#GiveawayModal').modal('hide');
    $('#GiveawayModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#EligibilityModal').modal('show');
    });
    console.log('wuzi');
});
```

```css
/* Modals */

.modal { overflow: auto !important; }

.modal-open {
  padding-right:0 !important;
}

.modal-lg {
    width: 90% !important;
    max-width: 1200px !important;
    
}

@media (max-width: 575px) { 
    .modal-lg {
        margin: 15px auto;    
    }
}

.modal-content {
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: none;
    
}

/* Giveaway Modal */

#GiveawayModal .modal-body {
    padding: 25px;
}


.giveawayHands {
    background-image: url('img/giveaway_popup_hands.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    
}

.Close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
}

.Close:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: Close;
  animation-name: Close;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.15s;
  animation-duration: 0.15s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Close {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }
}
@keyframes Close {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }
}

.giveawayTitle {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 64px;
    color: #191f4c;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.giveawayOrange {
    background-color: rgba(242,101,34,0.78);
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin: 25px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
}

.giveawayOrangeTop {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.giveawayOrangeBottom {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.giveawayFineprint {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 25px 15px;
    color: black;
}

.giveawayApplyNow {
    background-color: #008e39;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 287px;
    width: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid #008e39;
    margin: 20px auto 10px;
    transition: color .3s, background-color .3s;    
}

.giveawayApplyNow:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #008e39;
}

@media (max-width: 1288px) {     
    .giveawayTitle {
        margin-bottom: 450px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1080px) {     
    .giveawayTitle {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .giveawayHands {
        max-height: 841px;
    }
    
    .giveawayClose {
        width: 40px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 15px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 714px) { 
    .giveawayTitle {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 620px) { 
    .giveawayTitle {
        font-size: 40px;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .giveawayOrangeTop {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .giveawayOrangeBottom {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 418px) { 
    .giveawayTitle {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .giveawayOrangeTop {
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .giveawayOrangeBottom {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}

/* Eligible Modal */

.eligibilityTopMargin {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.orangeBorderRight {
    border-right: 3px solid #f26522;
}

.eligibilityBtn {
    background-color: #008e39;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 287px;
    width: 65%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid #008e39;
    margin: 60px auto 40px;
    transition: color .3s, background-color .3s;
}

.eligibilityBtn:hover {
    color: #008e39;
    background-color: white;
}


.eligibilitybtnSub {
    min-width: 287px;
    width: 65%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.AreYouEligible {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 29px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #f7941d;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.eligibleTick {
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.eligibleTickText {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.warningIcon {
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.warningText {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #f26522;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}


.eligibilityInfo {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: black;
}

.eligibilityInfo a {
    color: #f26522;
}

.eligibilityInfo a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.eligibilityList li {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.eligibilityFineprint {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
<div class="applyNowbtn">Apply Now</div>
<div class="learnMorebtn">Learn More</div>



<!-- Giveaway Popup -->    
<div class="modal fade" id="GiveawayModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="GiveawayModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="giveawayHands">
                    <img src="img/giveaway-close.svg" class="Close giveawayClose">
                    <div class="giveawayTitle">HANDEE’S $1000<br>WE’RE IN THIS TOGETHER<br>GIVEAWAY</div>
                    <div class="giveawayOrange">
                        <div class="giveawayOrangeTop">WE WANT TO THANK THE HANDEE COMMUNITY FOR SUPPORTING OUR LOCAL BUSINESS. APPLY NOW FOR YOUR CHANCE TO WIN</div>
                        <div class="giveawayOrangeBottom">ONE LUCKY HANDEE LOANS CLIENT WILL BE SELECTED EACH MONTH UNTIL THE END OF 2020 TO WIN $1000*</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="giveawayFineprint">*To be eligible you must be approved for a Handee Loan during the months of the competition. Competition runs from 1st July 2020 to 31st December 2020. Winner for each month will be announced after the month has ended.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="giveawayApplyNow">Apply Now</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
    
    
<!-- Eligibility Popup -->    
<div class="modal fade" id="EligibilityModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="EligibilityModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="img/giveaway-close.svg" class="Close eligibilityClose">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row eligibilityTopMargin">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 orangeBorderRight">
                            <div class="eligibilityBtn">New Client</div>
                            <h6 class="eligibilitybtnSub">I have not had a loan previously with Handee Loans</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="eligibilityBtn">Existing Client</div>
                            <h6 class="eligibilitybtnSub">I have previously been approved for a loan with Handee Loans</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="AreYouEligible">Are you eligible?</div>
                            <img class="eligibleTick" src="img/orangeTick.svg">
                            <div class="eligibleTickText">I'm a permanent Australia resident.</div><br>
                            <img class="eligibleTick" src="img/orangeTick.svg">
                            <div class="eligibleTickText">I'm paid $500 or more a week into my bank account.</div><br>
                            <img class="eligibleTick" src="img/orangeTick.svg">
                            <div class="eligibleTickText">I'm not in bankruptcy or part 9 agreement.</div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <img src="img/orangeWarning.svg" class="warningIcon">
                            <div class="warningText">WARNING: DO YOU REALLY NEED A LOAN TODAY?*</div><br>
                            <div class="eligibilityInfo">
                            It can be expensive to borrow small amounts of money and borrowing may not solve your money problems.<br><br>
                            Check your options <u>before</u> you borrow:   <ul class="eligibilityList">
                                <li>For information about other options for managing bills and debts, ring <a href="tel:1800007007">1800 007 007</a> from anywhere in Australia to talk to a free and independent financial counsellor.</li>
                                <li>Talk to your electricity, gas, phone or water provider to work out a payment plan.</li>
                                <li>If you are on government benefits, ask for an advance payment from Centrelink:<br> <a href="https://www.humanservices.gov.au/advancepayments" target="_blank">www.humanservices.gov.au/advancepayments</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            The Government’s <a href="https://moneysmart.gov.au">MoneySmart Website</a> shows you how small amount loans work and suggests other options that may help you.    
                            </div>
                            <div class="eligibilityFineprint">
                            * This statement is an Australian Government requirement under the National Consumer Credit Protection Act 2009.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of triggering next modal  .on('hidden.bs.modal').  Try showing next modal after a delay. like setTimeout(function(){ $('#EligibilityModal').modal('show'); },1000);

Comment: I am sure this would work, but I am hoping that there might be a better solution. I think something is wrong with how my function is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.on('hidden.bs.modal',...)` event adds an event listener that is triggered **every** time that `#GiveawayModal` is closed.

It seems like you want to only have this happen once (if the learn more button is clicked). Maybe use the jQuery [`.one(...)`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) method instead of `on(...)` to only add the event listener and then remove it after it has been triggered **only one time**.